# Looking for a list of the slackware packages needed to upgrade KDE Plasma

Tags: upgrade, kde, kde-plasma-5, slackware

I am in the process of upgrading from Slackware 14.2 to 15.0. I have encountered some hiccups in the version of KDE Plasma (5.23.5) included in 15.0. I got to looking and the KDE website says the current is 5.27 something and slackware64-current/kde is on version  5.27.2. So I figure now would be a good time to upgrade KDE Plasma and get all the bug fixes etc. for the new version. There are a lot of packages though in slackware64-current/kde and I am fairly sure that not all of them need to be upgraded just to upgrade Plasma.

So assuming the above is correct my question is: Does anyone have/know where I can find a list of the slackware64-current/kde packages I need to download to upgrade just plasma?

Comment: Any release from any distro has a tight DE integracion. This means everything is "designed" to run that specific version it has been bundled with. Certain rolling releases sometimes update DE components partially or more extensively with their own tested and/or experimental updates pushed through their update tool. Users  should NOT try to do it by themselves. The typical result being "no GUI".

Comment: I build my own kernels and write my own plasmoids so I am hardly an average user. Worst case I have to reinstall 15.0 from scratch which isn't a big deal for me and I would rather try now before I have settled in to my new system than wait and need to do it later when I would have to back up a bunch of stuff first.